# I want to correct my program and make it display the initial time as intended

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a programming that would set the time to 11/7/2018, but it's not working. It only display 4 errors. Can someone please help me rectify the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class date {
private: 
    int day,month,year;

public:
    void advance();

    date(){
        day=1;
        month=1;
        year=2018;
    };

    void setDate(){
        cout<<day<<"/"<<month<<"/"<<year<<endl;
    }
};

void date::advance(){
    for(month=1;month=<12;month++){
        for(day=1;day=<31;day++){
            cout<<day<<"/"<<month<<"/"<<year<<endl;
        }   
    }
}

int main(){
    date d;
    cout<<"Date set as:";
    d.setDate();
    cout<<"Setting the advance method"<<endl;
    d.advance();
    return 0;
}
```

It display In member function `void date::setDate()`:

```
[Error] expected primary-expression before '<<' token
In member function 'void date::advance()':
[Error] expected primary-expression before '<<' token
```

Comment: You are using `date` which isn't declared. You probably meant to use `day`. Also, as was pointed out by a now deleted comment, you should verify that you use `=` (assignment) correctly (comparison for equality would use `==`).

Comment: "it's not working. It only display 4 errors" is *not* a useful problem description. At the very least, show us the errors.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I agree that the formatting isn't ideal but it _does_ say `[Error] expected primary-expression before '<<' token` ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to write

```
cout<<day<<"/"<<month<<"/"<<year<<endl;
```

instead of

```
cout<<date<<"/"<<month<<"/"<<year<<endl;
```

in both the setDate and advance functions